Acess token call return null value for some field
I use spring boot with spring security and ms azure b2c
I get an acess token
    GetTokenRequestPayload req = new GetTokenRequestPayload(GRANT_TYPE_CREDENTIAL,certSecretValue, clientId, graphAPI ? configuration.getMsGraphScope() : configuration.getAppScope());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    
    // Construction du body de la requete
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("grant_type",req.getGrant_type());
    map.add("client_secret",req.getClient_secret());
    map.add("client_id",req.getClient_id());
    map.add("scope",req.getScope());
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
    
    ResponseEntity<TokenResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(configuration.getAccessGraphTokenUri(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, TokenResponse.class);

url called (modified value with ...)
https://login.microsoftonline.com/04a485d4-754c-4912-b891-..../oauth2/v2.0/token
grant type is client_credentials
Result is that

In the access token time value is ok...
"iat": 1716554210,
"nbf": 1716554210,
"exp": 1716558110,0,
Why azure sent me null value for many value?

I'm not sure I understood what your question is.

i edited the question, don't know why i get null value for the time from azure

According to the spec, there are very few mandatory parameters to the token response. Only access_token and token_type are.
Regarding some of the null values we can see on your screen-shot (which is a worst practice, you should put the JSON payload instead):

refresh_token: most authorization servers include it only if offline_access scope is requested and the refresh token flow is enabled for the client
in an HTTP response, expires_on is redundant with expires_in: you can infer the 1st from the 2nd when you receive this response. Note that in a token payload, expires_in would not make sense (but you can infer it from exp claim and current time)

In short, read the values you are interested in from the token claims (by decoding a JWT or introspecting an opaque token), not from the token response itself.
